# How to directly filter an unpivoted LazyDataFrame without having to collect?

Tags: node.js, nodejs-polars

I would like to filter an unpivoted LazyDataFrame by using [nodejs-polars](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/nodejs-polars/html/index.html) without having to collect (and lose the LazyDataFrame) in between.

Consider the following example csv's

1.csv:

```
asset_key
abc
```

| asset_key |
| --- |
| abc |

2.csv:

```
id;asset_key_1;asset_key_2;asset_key_3
1;123;456;abc
```

| id | asset_key_1 | asset_key_2 | asset_key_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 456 | abc |

I would first like to unpivot 2.csv, to have all asset_keys available in a new column. Then, I want to filter that column on the value available in 1.csv ("abc"), such that the remaining result after filtering would be:

| id | variable | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | asset_key_3 | abc |

Instead, I am getting an error

> "Error: Not found: value"

If I would collect the LazyDataFrame into a DataFrame after melting and before filtering, it does work. But I would like to know if there is a way to do this without having to give up the LazyDataFrame.

This is the code I use:

```
import * as pl from 'nodejs-polars';

const df_1: LazyDataFrame = pl.scanCSV('1.csv', { sep: ';' });
const df_2: LazyDataFrame = pl.scanCSV('2.csv', { sep: ';' });

const isInFilter: LazyDataFrame = df_1.select('asset_key');

const df: DataFrame = await df_2
  .melt('id', ['asset_key_1', 'asset_key_2', 'asset_key_3'])
  .dropNulls()
  .filter(pl.col('value').isIn(isInFilter['asset_key']))
  .collect();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this does look like a bug not only in nodejs-polars, but in polars as well. I opened up an issue for you! https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/4368